# Linux Command Line Search and Replace

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to programmatically change the AWS CloudFormation template. Its a JSON text document. In the CloudFormation template is an AMI ID that starts with AMI-plus 8 characters.

Is there a way to do a search and replace based on knowing the first four characters "AMI-" and replacing the next eight characters programatically?

We tried sed but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace any AMI-XXXXXXXX in the file with AMI-87654321, you should be able to use `sed "s/AMI-......../AMI-87654321/g"`